# How do I make this jquery code work in my RoR app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the Embedly API with this code:

```
$.embedly('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfamTmY5REw',
       {maxWidth: 600,
           elems: $('#element'),
         success: function(oembed, dict){
                    alert(oembed.title);
                  });
```

Now my question is where should I put this code in my ruby on rails directory? In my application.js file? And how do I call this code when a url is submitted via a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the embedly [examples](https://github.com/embedly/embedly-jquery/tree/master/examples/), specifically the Youtube one.

**Edit:**
All you need is to add `jquery.embedly.js` and `jquery.min.js` to your `public/js` folder and then place the script at the bottom of the page in your application.js (or leave it in the page if you want).

**Edit 2:** In your above example to call the code you just need to make a div with `#element` class. The script code would be either in the page or in your `Application.js`, wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function()`.

Comment: where do I get query.embedly.js?

Comment: ok, so I actually won't be inputting my own link, but rather a variable that holds the link of the video input by the user. Can I use the @video.video_url variable in my application.js file?

Comment: also don't forget to include the javascripts in `app/views/layouts/application.*`. Something like `javascript_include_tag :all` would work.

Comment: yeah, I've included the js files. Why would I need to explicitly link to the video url? That's the original youtube url that the user inputs. How do I ensure that all of this happens when a new video is created?

Comment: because right now I get this error: NoMethodError in VideosController#create

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.save

Comment: Sorry, I confused myself. If you're saving the url as a string I think you will need to do something like `link_to "Video", @video.video_url`.